# How to ask gson to avoid escaping json in a json response?

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a response object like this:

```
public class TestResponse {

    private final String response;
    private final ErrorCodeEnum error;
    private final StatusCodeEnum status;

    // .. constructors and getters here
}
```

I am serializing above class using Gson library as shown below:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().serializeNulls().create();
System.out.println(gson.toJson(testResponseOutput));
```

And the response I am getting back is shown below:

```
{
  "response": "{\"hello\":0,\"world\":\"0\"}",
  "error": "OK",
  "status": "SUCCESS"
}
```

As you can see, my json string in `"response"` field is getting escaped. Is there any way I can ask gson not to do that and instead return a full response like this:

```
{
  "response": {"hello":0,"world":"0"},
  "error": "OK",
  "status": "SUCCESS"
}
```

And also - Is there any problem if I do it above way?

**NOTE:** My `"response"` string will always be JSON string or it will be null so only these two values will be there in my `"response"` string. In `"response"` field, I can have any json string since this library is calling a rest service which can return back any json string so I am storing that in a string `"response"` field.

Comment: Did you find a suitable answer to this question?

Comment: @nickb I guess not yet.. If you have anything please feel free to write an answer.. May be that can help me a bit?

Comment: Sure, did you try out [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34181429/862594)? It should work for any arbitrary JSON!

Answer (score 14):

If your `response` field can be arbitrary JSON, then you need to:

1. Define it as an arbitrary JSON field (leveraging the JSON type system already built into GSON by defining it as the root of the JSON hierarchy - [`JsonElement`](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html))

   ```
   public class TestResponse {
       private final JsonElement response;
   }
   ```
2. Convert the `String` field to an appropriate JSON object representation. For this, you can use GSON's [`JsonParser`](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonParser.html) class:

   ```
   final JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();

   String responseJson = "{\"hello\":0,\"world\":\"0\"}";
   JsonElement json = parser.parse(responseJson); // Omits error checking, what if responseJson is invalid JSON?
   System.out.println(gson.toJson(new TestResponse(json)));
   ```

This should print:

```
{
  "response": {
    "hello": 0,
    "world": "0"
  }
}
```

It should also work for any valid JSON:

```
String responseJson = "{\"arbitrary\":\"fields\",\"can-be\":{\"in\":[\"here\",\"!\"]}}";
JsonElement json = parser.parse(responseJson);
System.out.println(gson.toJson(new TestResponse(json)));
```

Output:

```
{
  "response": {
    "arbitrary": "fields",
    "can-be": {
      "in": [
        "here",
        "!"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Works for me too. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old but just adding an potential answer in case it is needed.

Sounds like you just want to return the response without escaping.  Escaping is a good thing, it will help to prevent security issues and prevent your JS application from crashing with errors.

However, if you still want to ignore escaping, try:

`Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().disableHtmlEscaping().serializeNulls().create();`

Answer (score 1):

add simple TypeAdapter and use *jsonValue(value)*
gson 2.8.0

version 1:

```
  @Test
public void correctlyShow() {
    TestResponse2 src = new TestResponse2("{\"arbitrary\":\"fields\",\"can-be\":{\"in\":[\"here\",\"!\"]}}");
    Gson create = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(String.class, ADAPTER).create();

    Stopwatch createStarted = Stopwatch.createStarted();
    String json2 = create.toJson(src);
    System.out.println(json2 + " correctlyShow4 " + createStarted.stop());
}

public class TestResponse2 {
    private final String response;

    public TestResponse2(String response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

    public String getResponse() {
        return response;
    }
}

private static final TypeAdapter<String> ADAPTER = new TypeAdapter<String>() {
    @Override
    public String read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unsupported Operation !!!");
    }

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, String value) throws IOException {
        out.jsonValue(value);
    }
};
```

...

vesrion 2

```
@Test
public void correctlyShow() {
    TestResponse2 src = new TestResponse2("{\"arbitrary\":\"fields\",\"can-be\":{\"in\":[\"here\",\"!\"]}}");

    String json2 = new Gson().toJson(src);
    System.out.println(json2 + " correctlyShow4 ");
}

public class TestResponse2 {
    @JsonAdapter(value = AdapterStringJson.class)
    private final String response;

    public TestResponse2(String response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

    public String getResponse() {
        return response;
    }
}

private class AdapterStringJson extends TypeAdapter<String> {
    @Override
    public String read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unsupported Operation !!!");
    }

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, String value) throws IOException {
        out.jsonValue(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see it in the javadocs, but it doesn't appear to resolve, nor can I find any reference to it in the source. Did this get removed?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a nested object.

```
public class Response {
    private final Integer hello;
    private final String world;
}

public class TestResponse {
    private final Response response;
    private final ErrorCodeEnum error;
    private final StatusCodeEnum status;

    // .. constructors and getters here
}
```

Comment: It's not always hello and world. I am getting my JSON string which is in response field from another service. So in the response field it can be any JSON string.

Comment: So, you need to find a way to parse the json string as an object. Maybe this link can help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java

Answer (score 0):

The below code is avoiding escape characters. Use getAsString method.

```
jsonElementEntry.getValue().getAsString()


    JsonObject jsonObjectResponse = new JsonObject();
    String jsonResponseProcessed = null;
    try {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonObject jsonObject = gson.fromJson(jsonString, JsonObject.class);
        for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> jsonElementEntry : jsonObject.entrySet()) {
            String jsonElementEntryKey = jsonElementEntry.getKey();
            if (jsonElementEntryKey == null)    continue;
            boolean isIgnoreProperty = false;
            for (String ignorePropertyStr : IGNORE_JOB_PARAMETERS_LIST) {
                if (jsonElementEntryKey.startsWith(ignorePropertyStr)) {
                    isIgnoreProperty = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!isIgnoreProperty){
                jsonObjectResponse.addProperty(jsonElementEntryKey, jsonElementEntry.getValue().getAsString());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of a String, depending on your needs, you could use a Map (or similar) or a nested Object. There should not be a problem representing it this way but in your example, if it were a String, there would be a problem if you didn't escape characters such as the double-quote.